# How do you use ngrx/store when you have data with ids?

Tags: hashmap, uuid, ngrx-store

Let's say we have a list with 100 heroes. Each hero has an id and a name property, so the hero model would be:

```
interface Hero {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

I want to use ngrx/store with a hash-map (dictionary) datastructure for fast access of a single hero. So the hero-store would have the structure `Observable<{[heroId: string]: Hero}>`.

Then in my `hero-component` I want to load the hero by id, so it would look like:

```
<app-hero [heroId]="25"></app-hero>
```

and in the controller:

```
heroStore.subscribe(updatedStore => {
  this.hero = updatedStore[this.heroId];
}
```

This works, but it seems not ideal to me, since when **just one** hero is updated, in **all 100 components** the subscribe listener is triggered.

1. Does this have a negative impact on performance?
2. Is there a better way than this?

I thought about putting `Observable<Hero>` into the store instead of just `Hero` so the store would look like `Observable<{[heroId: string]: Observable<Hero>}>`

Then something like:

```
heroStore.getValue()[heroId].subscribe(hero => {
  this.hero = hero;
});
```

would be possible. But then again, this seems a little crazy. What's the suggested way of going about that? Or to be more specifically: **How do you handle a hash-mapped resource-store with ngrx/store**?